# Layout of a table, justify margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a table aligned to the center and I do not know why I cannot do it...

The script is as follows:

```
d3.text("../static/CSV/Chart_data/Tables/top2.csv", function(data) {
    var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

    var container = d3.select("#table1")
        .append("table")

        .selectAll("tr")
            .data(parsedCSV).enter()
            .append("tr")

        .selectAll("td")
            .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
            .append("td")
            .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
```

The table is displayed in the middle of an html website with code:

```
<div id="Access" hidden>                
    <div id="table1"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/scripts/table3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

And the css file with the styles:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 70%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {background-color:#f5f5f5;}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that `table`, which is a block like element, to center, you could use auto margin, e.g. like this

Stack snippet

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 70%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;             /*  added  */
    border: 1px dotted black    /*  for this demo  */
}

th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {background-color:#f5f5f5;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Cell with data</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

Based on a comment I added 2 more samples how to increase distance between rows/columns.

Sample 1 - cell border spacing

```css
table {
    border-collapse: seperate;    /*  changed from "collapse"  */
    width: 70%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;               /*  added  */
    border: 1px dotted black;     /*  for this demo  */
    
    border-spacing: 40px 20px;    /*  added  (need "border-collapse" to be "seperate")  */
}

th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {background-color:#f5f5f5;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td></tr>
</table>
```

Sample 2 - cell padding

```css
table {
    border-collapse: seperate;
    width: 70%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;               /*  added  */
    border: 1px dotted black;     /*  for this demo  */
}

th, td {
    padding: 28px;                /*  increased value  */
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {background-color:#f5f5f5;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td><td>Cell with data</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @LGSon and to add more line spacing? And space between columns? Thanks!

Comment: @MTT Check out _[`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)_ and _[`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)_

Comment: @MTT If you provide a small sample code so I can see what does not work, and I likely will be able to suggest how to do.

Comment: I want the above explained table to have more line spacing between each raw of data. And if possible, the columns of the table be more separated... @LGSon

Comment: @MTT Added a couple of samples